# Significance testing question

Tags: statistical-significance

If 2 distributions of data have the **same mean value** but **standard deviation** of sample 1 is twice the value of sample 2, explain what the difference in standard deviation value would indicate about the two distributions.

Totally stuck with this one.

Comment: Is this homework? if so, it should have the homework tag. And welcome to the site!

Comment: It's a task within a research module. I'm new to this site!

Comment: Think about this as a picture.  2 distributions have the same mean, which is the same as saying they are both centered at the same point on the x-axis.  The SD is a measure of how far from the mean, or how spread out the data tends to be.  So what would a SD 2X as big as another SD (with same means) say about its distribution?

Comment: Would it say that there is a larger variation of data and that the data is more widely distributed in sample 1 than sample 2?

Comment: Yes, Sample 1 has greater variation than Sample 2.

Comment: Ok, thanks! Are there any guidelines that I could read in relation to this that would help answering the rest of the questions?

Comment: At CV, we generally ask that you mark a question as answered when your question is resolved.  I'm going to post some resources as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Not knowing the rest of the questions within your research module, I can point you to the following references for further study:

[A general description of mean and standard deviation, with an example and useful equations](http://scienceblogs.com/goodmath/2008/03/24/basic-statistics-mean-and-stan/),

[A slightly more technical discussion of the above](https://controls.engin.umich.edu/wiki/index.php/Basic_statistics%3a_mean,_median,_average,_standard_deviation,_z-scores,_and_p-value),

[A Khan Academy video on the topic](https://www.khanacademy.org/test-prep/california-standards-test/california-standards-test-algebra-2/v/algebra-ii--mean-and-standard-deviation).